# Panel Administrativo Para Usuarios Registrados - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy realizando un panel administrativo para los usuarios que se registran en mi sitio web, para esto hago uso del plugin Ultimate member pero quiero añadirle otros menus en el dashboard. De momento estas son las opciones que por defecto muestra el plugin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera lograr algo parecido a esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado modificar desde los ajustes de plugin pero no ha sido posible, al igual que agregar una nueva pagina en el menú pero no se refleja en el menú lateral, se posiciona en la barra de navegación, también e intentado agregar código personalizado en el archivo de functions.php y no toma los cambios tampoco. Sera que el plugin no deja realizar este tipo de personalizaciones o habrá algún otro que cumpla con lo que requiero.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para registrar menús en Ultimate Member debes de conectarte a ciertos hooks y filtros, por ejemplo, para registrar una tab debes de usar el filtro `um_account_page_default_tabs_hook`, luego obtener la tab con `um_account_tab__info` y `get_tab_output` para luego crear un area donde se mostrara el contenido usando `um_account_content_hook_` que recibirá la salida de nuestra tab.

Por ejemplo:

```
// Registramos nuestra TAB
function my_custom_tab_in_um( $tabs ) {
    // Creamos una nueva Tab y la guardamos en la variable $tabs
    $tabs[100]['imagenes']['icon'] = 'um-icon-android-list';
    $tabs[100]['imagenes']['title'] = 'Mis Imagenes';
    $tabs[100]['imagenes']['custom'] = true;
    return $tabs;
}
add_filter('um_account_page_default_tabs_hook', 'my_custom_tab_in_um', 100 );

// Asignamos la salida de nuestra tab
function um_account_tab__info( $imagenes ) {
    global $ultimatemember; // Ingresamos a la variable Global $ultimatemember
    extract( $imagenes ); // Obtenemos la tab $imagenes que registramos anteriormente
    $output = $ultimatemember->account->get_tab_output('imagenes'); // Obtenemos la informacion y la guardamos en la Variable $output
    if ( $output ) { echo $output; }
}
add_action('um_account_tab__info', 'um_account_tab__info');

// Área de contenido para la nueva Tab
function um_account_content_hook_imagenes( $output ){ 

    // Creamos el area de contenido para nuestra variable $output
    ob_start();

    // Agrega tu contenido aquí
    echo '<h2>Mis Imagenes</h2>  ';

    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;

}
add_filter('um_account_content_hook_imagenes', 'um_account_content_hook_imagenes');
```

Con eso solo tienes que repetir el proceso para crear mas tabs modificando solo el nombre y la variable que contendrá la tab,

Por ejemplo, este codigo creara dos Tabs, Imagenes y Reportes

```
/**** TABLA DE IMAGENES ****/

// Tabla de Imagenes
function my_custom_tab_in_um( $tabs ) {
  $tabs[100]['imagenes']['icon'] = 'um-icon-android-list';
  $tabs[100]['imagenes']['title'] = 'Mis Imagenes';
  $tabs[100]['imagenes']['custom'] = true;
  return $tabs;
}
add_filter('um_account_page_default_tabs_hook', 'my_custom_tab_in_um', 100 );

// Asignamos la salida de nuestra tab
function um_account_tab__info( $imagenes ) {
  global $ultimatemember;
  extract( $imagenes );

  $output = $ultimatemember->account->get_tab_output('imagenes');
  if ( $output ) { echo $output; }
}
add_action('um_account_tab__info', 'um_account_tab__info');

// Área de contenido para la nueva Tab
function um_account_content_hook_imagenes( $output ){ ob_start(); ?>
    
  <!--== Contenido Aquí ==-->
   <h2>Mis Imagenes</h2>   
    
  <?php
    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
  }
add_filter('um_account_content_hook_imagenes', 'um_account_content_hook_imagenes');

/**** TABLA DE REPORTES ****/

// Tabla de Reportes
function my_custom_tab_in_um_reportes( $tabs ) {
  $tabs[100]['reportes']['icon'] = 'um-icon-android-list';
  $tabs[100]['reportes']['title'] = 'Reportes';
  $tabs[100]['reportes']['custom'] = true;
  return $tabs;
}
add_filter('um_account_page_default_tabs_hook', 'my_custom_tab_in_um_reportes', 100 );

// Asignamos la salida de nuestra tab usando get_tab_output
function um_account_tab__info_reportes( $reportes ) {
  global $ultimatemember;
  extract( $reportes );

  $output = $ultimatemember->account->get_tab_output('reportes');
  if ( $output ) { echo $output; }
}
add_action('um_account_tab__info', 'um_account_tab__info_reportes');

// Área de contenido para la nueva Tab
function um_account_content_hook_reportes( $output ){ ob_start(); ?>

    <!--== Contenido Aquí ==-->
    <h2>Reportes</h2>  
    
  <?php
    $output .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
  }
add_filter('um_account_content_hook_reportes', 'um_account_content_hook_reportes');
```

Agregando esto en tu archivo functions o bien con un plugin de snippets, recomiendo usar `is_plugin_active` para verificar que el plugin este activo antes de ejecutar el codigo.

Fuentes: https://docs.ultimatemember.com/category/955-hooks

Comment: Excelente tu aporte @Jefferzon Bol, lo pude crear el menu, voy a leer la documentación del link que me adjuntas, gracias